# sed issue - Extract specific words from file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I would like to get some help with SED.

I'm trying to extract some files from a file, all the words that I need start like this.

```
39;,bugs.pr~%3D~&#39;TEXT23
```

I need to get TEXT23 for example.

What I did what, first, change 39;,bugs.pr~%3D~' for IDEX which is my flag, then seach for IDEX and extract 8 characters from that word.

Comment: This may be a correct solution... what is the problem then?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to show us your input,output, code and error messages. Good luck.

Comment: Would you considering editing your original question to discuss the pattern you want to eliminate and the one you want to keep? sed is an interesting utility, and there may be other ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sed command might eliminate all text but what you want.

```
sed 's/^39;,bugs.pr~%3D~&#39;//p;d' file
```